# App Engine + NoseGAE bizarre broken test

Tags: google-app-engine, unit-testing

I'm using the NoseGAE to write local unit tests for my App Engine application, however something is suddenly going wrong with one of my tests. I have standard setUp and tearDown functions, but one test seemingly broke for a reason I can't discern. Even stranger, setUp and tearDown are NOT getting called each time. I added global variables to count setUp/tearDown calls, and on my 4th test (the now seemingly broken one), setUp has been called twice and tearDown has been called once. Further, one of the objects from the third test exists when I query it by id, but not in a general query for its type. Here's some code that gives the bizarre picture:

```
class GameTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
       self.testapp = webtest.TestApp(application)
       self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
       self.testbed.activate()
       self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(
           consistency_policy=datastore_stub_util.PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy(probability=1),
           require_indexes=True,
           root_path="%s/../../../" % os.path.dirname(__file__)
        )

    def tearDown(self):
        self.testbed.deactivate()
        self.testapp.cookies.clear()

    def test1(self):
        ...

    def test2(self):
        ...

    def test3(self):
       ...
       # I create a Game object with the id 123 in this particular test
       Game(id=123).put()
       ...

    def test4(self):
       print "id lookup: ", Game.get_by_id(123)
       print "query: ", Game.query().get()
       self.assertIsNone(Game.get_by_id(123))
```

This is an abstraction of the tests, but illustrates the issue.

The 4th test fails because it asserts that an object with that id does not exist. When I print out the two statements:

id lookup:  Game(key=Key('Game', 123))

query: None

The id lookup shows the object created in test3, but the query lookup is EMPTY. This makes absolutely no sense to me. Further, I am 100% sure the test was working earlier. Does anyone have any idea how this is even possible? Could I possibly have some local corrupted file causing an issue?

Comment: I've never been able to get nose-gae working properly with NDB unless I run  nosetests with --without-sandbox. It fails in weird and confusing ways, with (seemingly) no consistent reason ... I hope someone can give a decent answer, but trying with that option might help you in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks Greg, but I should mention that I'm already running it with that flag.

Comment: This is the kind of behavior to expect with a `PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy` set with a probability < 1. Are you able to assert that your policy is being initiated as you expect?

Comment: To address a second concern you had about the number of times setUp and tearDown are called, I've added this to setUp to avoid any inconsistencies, which I was also experiencing: `def setUp(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_test_setup_complete") or not self._test_setup_complete:
            self._test_setup_complete = True`

Comment: The probability of the HR consistency policy is set to 1, so that is not the issue. What I have noticed and didn't expect is that the tests aren't run in the order I wrote them on the unittest.TestCase class. That's why I thought there was an issue with setUp/tearDown not being called; I saw 2 setUp calls by the 4th test, but in reality, the 4th test was actually just called 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

I somewhat "solved" this. This issue only reproduced when I had other test cases in other files that were failing. Once I solved those, all my tests passed. I still don't fully understand why other failing tests should cause these bizarre issues with the testbed, but to anyone else having this issue, try fixing your other test cases first and see if that doesn't cause it to go away.